# how to find a digit before a substring in a value of dictionary

Tags: python, database, string, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary in python and it includes 200 keys and each key has long strings and several lines as a value

EXAMPLE OF DICTIONARY

```
var_holder = {
    'text0': 'Montgomery\n\nBirmingham 20 houses/ 30 persons. Phoenix\n\nSacramento ,\nChicago\n\nSpringfield: Atlanta\n\x0c',
    'textn': ' other strings but same values 20 houses/ 30 persons'
    }
```

WHAT I NEED is to extract the number before houses and the number before persons

EXPECTED OUTPUT x= 20 and y= 30

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can do this with a simple regular expression.

Comment: From which text were those numbers extracted and why? `text0` or `textn`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller well the keys are from text0 till text 200 are created by a loop.

Comment: Why is the output `x=20 and y=30` and not `x=20 and y=30 \n x=20 and y=30`? The numbers appear twice in the list of texts.
What if there's only `houses` or only `persons` in the text, but not both?

Comment: @Barmar as I said any help will be appreciated ^_^

Comment: Can your text span multiple lines like `text15: "There are 2", text16: "0 hou", text17: "ses"`?

Comment: Maybe any help is appreciated, but as @Barmar pointed out, not every question is appreciated. Please read through his links. From the number of questions I am asking, you hopefully notice that your question lacks plenty of detail.

Comment: @ThomasWeller since they will always be the same numbers in all the keys that's why I need to extract them only once. is there something wrong with my thinking?

Comment: @ThomasWeller everything in the strings is different the only constant thing is 20 houses/ 30 persons

Comment: What kind of help can I give without actually doing it? `\d+` is the regular expression for an integer. How much more do you need to know?

Comment: You can loop over all the values with `for text in var_holder.values():`

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks, because of your questions I realized something which made me changes my approach, and with the help of the commands that were mentioned by Barmar I could solve my problem thank you both

Answer (score 1):

since the values are predictable in my example I made another dictionary and compared both of them as the following

```
var_holder = {
    'text0': 'Montgomery\n\nBirmingham 20 houses/ 30 persons. Phoenix\n\nSacramento ,\nChicago\n\nSpringfield: Atlanta\n\x0c',
    'textn': ' other strings but same values 20 houses/ 30 persons'
}
 
amount = {
        '1': '50 houses/ 100 persons',
        '2': '30 houses/ 50 persons',
        '3': '80 houses/ 80 persons',
        '4': '40 houses/ 60 persons',
        '5': '20 houses/ 30 persons',
        '6': '90houses/ 700 persons',
}
x = 1
while x <= len(amount):
        value = amount.__getitem__(str(x))
        if any(value in v for v in var_holder.values()):
            print(f"Yes, Value: '{value}' exists in dictionary")
            m=1
            break
        else:
            print(f"No, Value: '{value}' does not exists in dictionary")
            x=x+1
```